# What is the Probability that the remaining marble from the same bag is also white given 3 bags each containing 2 marbles.?

Tags: probability

> You have 3 bags each containing two marbles.
>
> Bag A contains 2 white marbles ,
>
> Bag B contains 2 black marbles,
>
> Bag C contains one white marble and one black marble.
>
> You pick a random bag and take out one marble. It is a white marble.
>
> What is the Probability that the remaining marble from the same bag is also white?

My Approach:

A:Probability from choosing marble from bag $A=1/3$

B:Probability from choosing marble from bag $B=1/3$

C:Probability from choosing a marble from bag $C=1/3$

D:Probability of a white marble

$p(d/a)=2/2=1$

$p(d/b)=0$

$p(d/c)=1/2$

$p(d)=1/3*1=1/3$

Is it Correct?

correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Given that you selected a white marble on the first draw, you could not have selected bag B.

Comment: @N.F  Taussing Yes

Comment: You could do a formal conditional probability calculation. Let $W$ be the event first marble picked was white and $A$ be the event the marble came from $A$. We want $\Pr(A|W)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap W)}{\Pr(W)}$. Each of the probabilities on the right is not hard to compute.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sir What is your Ans My Ans is 1/3 according to your logic.Please Explain in detail here too :P .

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap W)=1/3$, $\Pr(W)=1/3+1/6=1/2$, ratio simplifies to $2/3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three white marbles.   You have selected one of these.   You want the probability that the one you selected comes from bag A, which held *two* of the *three*.

---

Or if you prefer to do it the *hard way*, use Bayes' Rule:

$$\mathsf P(A\mid W) = \frac{\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(W\mid A)}{\mathsf P(W)} = \frac{\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 2 2}{\tfrac 3 6} = \frac 2 3
$$

Comment: @Grham Kemp Not understood please explain in detail.

Comment: I think he means that the only way you can select a white marble and then another white would be if you selected bag *A* so the probability is $1/3$, the probability of selecting bag *A* @Jack

Comment: @Black No.  Jack cannot have selected bag B, and bag A contained twice as many white marbles as bag C (all equally likely to have been chosen).

Answer (score 2):

2/3. There are 3 possibilities, 2 of which are from bag A and 1 from bag C.

There are 3 marbles you might have picked :

AW1, AW2, CW

2/3 of these (the first 2) are from a bag where the other is white. Make sense?

Comment: Why my ans is wrong i haven't understood.

Comment: I edited, please respond if it's now understood.

Comment: yes it is understood :)